# Delete all action in a table

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, tables, error-message, data-tables

I have a table with certain records as shown below :

[image]

If I select all the records and delete them via delete button,what approach is best for the after scenario's :

- Retain the table headers and within the table body display a message
  like "**Records deleted successfully**"
- Clear the table all together including headers and show the relevant
  message?

Answer (score 1):

First option is much more explanatory for the user. I would use some blank slate that describes the cause (why the table is empty, who & when erased it) and possible actions that can be undertaken (Undo, Import of new data). If your product allows to manually fill in the table, you need some empty rows at the beginning, with option to add more of them. Disabling the table header actions might work too.

If you remove the whole table, you must assure that it won't be seen as a bug.